# How to revert the pixastic effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixastic

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
jQuery(".attachment-thumbnail")
.pixastic("desaturate")
.pixastic("sepia")
});
</script>
```

I got this pixastic script working, now I need to revert the effects on rollover. I don't really know how to do that though.
The link is here if you want to take a look, http://mentor.com.tr/wp/?page_id=218

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(".attachment-thumbnail").live({
  mouseenter: function() {       
     Pixastic.revert(this);

  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    jQuery(this).pixastic("desaturate");
  }
});
```

Note that `sepia` won't do anything combined with `desaturate`

The plugin is not very well documented, so in the future I suggest taking a look into the source code, in this example `line 403` shows

```
revert : function(img) {
```

Comment: I thought I needed a .mouseout function? It didn't work for me.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. They should be desaturated by default and when user hovers over them they revert, i mean they gain saturation back again. But this happens only when the cursor is on the images.

Comment: @Talha do you mean to saturate them, and they shouldn't go back to desaturation? in that case just remove `, mouseleave: function() {..}`

Comment: @Talha BTW in this website you should show your prior attempts and not expect people to do work for you, just help.

Comment: No, right now it's doing exactly opposite of what I was aiming. Initially the images has to be desaturated by pixastic. And when I hover over an image that image has to be saturated and when rollout they should go back to their desaturated state.

Comment: @Talha you have removed your original code. keep it, add mine below

Comment: d'oh! Thanks. I'll vote-up your answer once I've enough reputation. thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".thumb").pixastic('desaturate');
    $(".thumb").live({
        mouseenter: function() {
            Pixastic.revert(this);

        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).pixastic("desaturate");
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys everything said above works great if you're directly setting hover events on the image.
Whereas in my situation I wanted the the image to blur if I hover on the image container (which contains other divs too, not just the image).

Here is my code in case anyone else is dealing with something similar:

```
$(function () {

    $('.col1.w1').mouseenter(function () {

        var origImg = ($(this).find('.imageUrl'));
        if (origImg.is('img')) {
            Pixastic.process(origImg[0], 'blurfast', { amount: 2 });
        }

    });
    $('.col1.w1').mouseout(function () {
        var origImg = ($(this).find('.imageUrl'));
        Pixastic.revert($(this).find('.imageUrl')[0]);

    });
});
```